# Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense's BMI270 accelerometer rev 2

Tags: accelerometer, arduino-nano-ble

I'm trying to figure out how to use interrupts to get BMI270 acceleration data at high rate, but can't find any info on it. Already spent a few hours looking for some sample code and found nothing. Anyone knows where can I find more info or sample code on this?
EDIT:
its the [rev 2](https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/nano-33-ble-sense-rev2) and it has a BMI270

Comment: By BMI270 do you mean LSM9DS1?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention its rev 2 (https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/nano-33-ble-sense-rev2)